# How can I create interactions between categorical variables with Sklearn?

Tags: logistic, scikit-learn, categorical-encoding

**How can I create interactions between categorical variables with Sklearn?**

I have two predictors that are the hour of the day and the day of the week (DOW). The model is a Binary Logistic Regression that is going to predict if an event happens or not. The occurrence of the event depends on the combination of the hour and DOW e.g. it's more likely to happen on Friday at 3:00 than on Tuesday at 3:00. Both DOW and hour are categorical variables. So far I have one hot encoded them. I know I can combine them through PolynomialFeatures but that wouldn't make sense with dummy variables. How can I properly create the interaction between these two variables with Sklearn? As a side note: I know I can use seasonal / cyclic splines for the hour but I want to know how can this be done in sklearn regardless.